# How to access a scope if its name is being used as a query column

Tags: url, coldfusion, scope, cfquery

Dealing with some legacy code we came across a rather annoying situation. We are looping through a query with the `<cfoutput query="x">` tag. That query has a column named 'url'. Within that loop we need to check if a key exists within the url scope. Since CF puts a priority on what's in the query over general page scopes I can't use a `structKeyExists(url,"key")` since as far as CF is concerned at this point, url is a string with the value from the current row of the query.

How can I break out of the query scope and inspect what's in my url?

As a temporary we are using isDefined("url.key"), but I would still like to know if there is a way to break out of the query scope.

Also can't really change the column, or even the column name in the query without a few hours of work tracking down an changing all references to it, so we're going to avoid that if at all possible.

**EDIT**:
There seems to be some confusion as to how this code is set up, and why the simple solutions don't apply. It would be hard for me to give a thorough example but I will try to clarify the situation.

There are many pages that would count as 'pageA' for the following example. Enough that changing how things work would require a change in scope and investment in time that's just not going to happen in the time allotted.

PageA runs a query with one of the columns being named url, then starts an output loop via cfoutput, inside that loop PageB is included. One PageA may have different variables in the URL scope than another PageA, actually they are the same, but may be named differently(varID=x in one case vid=x in another). Inside of PageB I need to use the value from that url scope, so I want to run through the different possible names (if key 'varID' exists in url, use it, otherwise use 'vid').

This is why I want to "punch through" the query scope to get the url structure, and not the url column from the query. Any other method seems to require modifying the many PageAs.

So the question is not how to solve this problem specifically, as there are many ways to do it, I would just really like to avoid them as they all add a lot of time in implementation and testing. The question remains, is there a way to access the url scope as a variable if url exists as a query column and you are in the query scope.

Comment: In addition to Henry's question, what about creating a pointer to `URL` (before the loop) ie `<cfset URLScope = URL/>`. Then use the new variable name with `structKeyExists`

Comment: Use [Railo](http://getrailo.org)? It has the deliberate difference that scope names are protected, i.e. using just `url` always refers to the scope (you would use `x.url` to get the query's column).

Comment: @Leigh - that would work and it's already been considered but would take almost as much work as rewriting it correctly, guess what management doesn't want to give us the time to do. This is why I'm specifically looking for a way to reach out from within the query scope.

Comment: @Peter Boughton - I am not given the time to just rewrite it correctly, what makes you think I could get management to allow for a server  change?

Comment: @invertedSpear - Can you show us a small example?

Comment: @PeterBoughton not one of the better examples of "being helpful" from you, Peter?

Comment: What bit is not helpful? He's got working code, and he's got suggestions for improvements, but he's discounting them on account of not being allowed the time to implement; i.e. the issue isn't really finding better code. _IF_ he's open to convincing his managers why fixing bad code is important then people can make appropriate suggestions on that factor.

Comment: Suggesting he uses Railo instead of CF wasn't likely to be (as as pointed out: wasn't) very helpful. Usually you just give good, balanced (and non-partisan) advice.

Comment: It's directly relevant and _potentially_ less effort than changing lots of code. If his response to Leigh had come in first I probably wouldn't have commented, and likewise if I'd been awake enough to think about getPageContext, but excluding those I stand by it as a potentially worthwhile consideration.

Comment: Re: *is there a way to access the url scope as a variable if url exists as a query column and you are in the query scope.* Did you look at [peter's second suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18421765/104223)? AFAIK, that is as close as it gets in ACF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought it might work to create a function that returned the url scope, but upon testing it, even with a local-scoped query (which prevents the function using the query itself) the use of `url` inside the function is still corrupted:

```
<cffunction name="getUrlScope"><cfreturn Url /></cffunction>
...
<cfoutput query="x">
<cfif StructKeyExists( getUrlScope() , 'key' )>
    <!--- still fails :( --->
```

There is however an undocumented (meaning unsupported and liable to change) option. If you dump `getPageContext()` you will see a bunch of functions that do interesting things, including dealing with scopes.

**You can use `getPageContext().SymTab_findBuiltinScope('URL')` to get at the URL scope.**

You can also use `getPageContext().getCfScopes()` to get an array of scopes. I'm not sure if the order is guaranteed fixed but it seems to be [cgi,?,url,form,cookie,?] checking on both CF10 and cflive (CF9), so possibly is.

(In CF8 there was [the method getBuiltinScopes](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2008/7/29/get-all-scopes-for-a-request), which returned a struct instead of an array - this no longer appears to exist, reinforcing the whole unsupported and changeable nature of these methods.)

On Railo those don't work, but there is `getPageContext.UrlScope()` and similarly-named functions for the other scopes.

Comment: Re: *getUrlScope* Might work. Though I think you would need to put it in a component, otherwise you would run into the same scoping clashes based on how ACF evaluates variable references in functions. (Edit) Ahh.. looks like getPageContext().SymTab_findBuiltinScope('URL') works.

Comment: I just tested and it's still referring to the query column, even if you local-scope the query (which prevents access to the query variable itself), somehow it still refers to the column name. :/

Comment: Yeah, but your second suggestion ie getPageContext().SymTab_findBuiltinScope('URL') should work ... or at least it seemed to when I ran a (very) quick test a few minutes ago.

Comment: Yeah, seems to work on CF9 and CF10, though as the answer now points out it's not guaranteed to exist in future. Of course, since CF8 had a different function that no longer exists it _might_ be less likely to change again. \*shrug\*

Comment: *not guaranteed to exist in future* Pay to fix it now .. or pay to fix it later ;-)

Comment: `getPageContext().SymTab_findBuiltinScope('URL')` seems to be the right answer for now, and since CF9 is supposed to be the last version of CF we use, this will hold until this page gets migrated. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be to assign the `url` struct to a new variable outside of the `cfoutput` tag and then reference that variable instead of `url`. Example:

```
<cfset urlScope = url>

<cfoutput query="x">
  <cfset keyExists = structKeyExists(urlScope, "key")>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Actually he said something about copying, which should not be necessary. (I mentioned the reference variable in the comments above). Assuming they are stuck w/ACF, and need to do the lookups inside the loop, that is probably the simplest work-around. Though most likely it is for a cfif construct, rather cfset.

Comment: It's a good thought, but due to the way the pages are included from other pages out would take me just as long to implement as just doing it right. That's why I'm specifically testing to see if there's a way out of the query scope from within the output loop.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample of how the "pages are being included from other pages"? I think that would help us understand the issue better.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for this is always to alias the url column in the query as int

```
SELECT URL as qURL FROM myTable ...
```

IF you don't have access to the query (it's a stored precedure or used elswhere etc) you can always use query of a query to reselect it with your alias.

I don't care for the idea of creating a separate reference to URL outside the output - but that would also work. I just want to KNOW what is user input (i.e. comes from the URL or FORM) and what is generated internally (i.e. comes from a query).

Comment: I do not particularly like the idea either, but I know dealing with legacy code sometimes requires .. compromises ;-) So just throwing out ideas.  That said - @invertedSpear if using a simple shadow variable will require massive changes then any "fix" will probably fall into the "..cure is worse than the disease" category.  In which case, you are better off redoing it the right way anyway. (Edit: I would still like to see a sample to get a better handle on the scope of the issue - no pun intended)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you move structKeyExists(url,"key") outside of the cfoutput block, and store that into a variable?  Or do a structAppend to copy the url struct into another struct named something else?

Comment: Yes, but no. I don't have the time to re-architect the thing, and things are being done by including a page in an output loop from one of several other pages. It's bad code, but it works, and I'm stuck with it for now.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to replace your cfoutput block with a cfloop block.

```
<cfloop from="1' to = "#YourQuery.recordcount#" index = "idx">
<cfif StructKeyExits(url,"key")>
<cfoutput>
#url.key# is not the same as #YourQuery.url[idx]#
which can also be referenced like this #YourQuery["url"][idx]
etc
```

Comment: ... I think you forgot to finish your thoughts, Dan?