# Cfscript for loop duplicating?

Tags: for-loop, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I'm getting duplicates in an array I'm building in a for loop in `<cfscript>` tags. What could be the cause of this?

I'm trying to build an array to later parse into JSON, using a query from the database. I've checked, and the result query object doesn't contain duplicate rows; it has two individual rows, although in the array resulting of the for loop, I only get the first row twice.

```
l.response.body.result = ArrayNew(1);
for(l.i=1;l.i lte l.events.recordcount;l.i = (l.i + 1)){
  ArrayAppend(l.response.body["result"], StructNew());
  l.eventIndex = ArrayLen(l.response.body["result"]);
  l.response.body["result"][l.eventIndex]["id"] = l.events.id;
  l.response.body["result"][l.eventIndex]["start"] = DateDiff("s","1/1/1970",l.events.startdate) * 1000;
  l.response.body["result"][l.eventIndex]["end"] = DateDiff("s","1/1/1970",l.events.enddate) * 1000;
  l.response.body["result"][l.eventIndex]["title"] = l.events.title;
  l.response.body["result"][l.eventIndex]["class"] = "class";
  l.response.body["result"][l.eventIndex]["url"] = l.url;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: are there more records in the array than the `recordCount`?

Comment: also fyi - you can use `l.i++` instead of `l.i = (l.i + 1)`

Comment: No - there is the same amount of records in the array as in the query. And yes, I know I can use `l.i++`. I just thought it might have something to do with that, but it (obviously) doesn't.

Comment: is the last row of your array the same as the last row of the query?

Comment: not sure what your end result is, but you can use `serializeJSON()` to convert your query to JSON.

Comment: I dunno if it's your problem but you've got a bit of an arse-backwards way of appending a struct to the array. Don't append and empty struct then populate the last array element's struct: populate the new struct, then append it. It'll make your code a lot tidier. Gist demonstrating what I mean: https://gist.github.com/adamcameroncoldfusion/6353377

Comment: This has nothing to do with your issue, but .. naming a column "url" is a bad idea, as `url` is reserved word in CF. So [it can cause problems in certain situations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413893/how-to-access-a-scope-if-its-name-is-being-used-as-a-query-column). If possible, you should rename or alias the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind this, I was being extremely stupid :) I was confusing `cfloop` with `for` loops, thinking it would only take one row of the query :) I changed it to this:

```
l.response.body.result = ArrayNew(1);
for(l.i=1;l.i lte l.events.recordcount;l.i = (l.i + 1)){
  ArrayAppend(l.response.body["result"], StructNew());
  l.eventIndex = ArrayLen(l.response.body["result"]);
  l.response.body["result"][l.eventIndex]["id"] = l.events.id[l.i];
  l.response.body["result"][l.eventIndex]["start"] = DateDiff("s","1/1/1970",l.events.startdate[l.i]) * 1000;
  l.response.body["result"][l.eventIndex]["end"] = DateDiff("s","1/1/1970",l.events.enddate[l.i]) * 1000;
  l.response.body["result"][l.eventIndex]["title"] = l.events.title[l.i];
  l.response.body["result"][l.eventIndex]["class"] = "class";
  l.response.body["result"][l.eventIndex]["url"] = l.url;
}
```

Comment: See my comment above. You're writing a lot more code than you need to / ought to.

Comment: Implicit creation of structs doesn't seem to work in cfscript in ColdFusion 8. It's giving me "Missing argument name".

Comment: @gdscei - IIRC, implicit structures are supported, but creation within another another function is not. So you would need to modify the example to create the structure on one line. Then append it to the array on another line. `<cfset data = {yourKeysAndValuesHere}> <cfset arrayAppend(arrayAppend(l.response.body["result"], data)>`. IMO, that style is more readable.

Comment: Irrespective of syntax, building the struct and then appending it is less repetition of code than appending an empty struct then working out how long the array is, and poking struct keys into the struct which happens to be at the end of the array. And, having had to describe it that way... it's more logical too ;-)

Comment: As an aside / for future reference... given you're using a dead version of CF, it would be helpful if you tag your questions "coldfusion-8" as well as "coldfusion". I'd've given you a CF8-specific answer had I known to.

Comment: Yeah, I've forgotten to include that tag, normally I'd add it. We have a policy to support CF8, so we're stuck to it for maybe 2 years to come. That's why I'm using a "dead version of CF".