# Circumvent closure in a CFML function expression

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, railo, cfml

I've full discussed the requirement and my investigations thusfar on my blog: "[Can a function expression circumvent closure?](http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/11/can-function-expression-circumvent.html)"

In summary, when one has this code:

```
o = new C();

function dumpVariables(){
    writeDump(var=variables);
}

o.dumpVariables = dumpVariables;
o.dumpVariables();
```

Then the `writeDump()` will reference the CFC's internal variables scope. However if one uses a function expression instead of a declaration:

```
dumpVariables = function (){
    writeDump(var=variables);
};
```

(The rest of the code being the same, just how the `dumpVariables()` function is created)

... then - because function expressions use closure when binding variable references, that reference to `variables` in the `writeDump()` statement still references the calling code's variables scope, even when it's being called from within the object the function has been injected into.

This is a very simplified repro case for the purposes of asking this question, so the stipulation is that the the function being injected into the object *must be* created via a function expression, and the other stipulation is that the function expression is the only code I can change. I say this because I'm fully aware of work-arounds for this which don't use function expressions, or leverage changes to the CFC code etc... that's not my problem. The problem I am having and am hoping someone can help with is **how one can access the variable context of when the function is *called* rather than when it's being *declared***.

Thanks for any insight. I suspect the answer is "cannot be done".

Comment: I wonder if writedump(var=this); would work better

Comment: (I covered that in the blog article, towards the bottom). Yeah, it coincidentally works OK, and I'll use that if I need to. However, it's a less than ideal solution in the actual context.

Comment: Don't have time to actually test if it's relevant, and I only quickly scanned the blog article to check if it's mentioned, but for a similar case of scope masking, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413893/how-to-access-a-scope-if-its-name-is-being-used-as-a-query-column/18421765#18421765 - possibly useful stuff there?

Comment: Cheers @PeterBoughton, yeah, someone mentioned that in response to a situation I had very much the same as the one in that other question you link to (my case: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/10/blocked-request.html). It does not help here.